# Conditional breakpoint depends on other breakpoint

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I need to stop at breakpoint in case when other breakpoint was passed. Is it possible realize in VC++?

Comment: how did you use another breakpoint? what does "passed" means? If there are two breakpoints, what is the relationship between them? If it stopped in breakpoint 1, and then you debug your app like use the Step Into, why not set the previous code line( the code in breakpoint 1) as a condition? So it could stop in breakpoint 2 if you debug your app step by step.

Comment: Yes, there are tow breakpoints A and B. I would like to as VS to stop at B only in case when was stop on A in current run.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you debug your two breakpoint using this way? If the debugging runs to the specific code line, it would call the conditional, and then trigger the conditional breakpoint, if it just runs to A code line, I don't think it could call the conditional in B code line unless it really calls/runs to this line.

Comment: I need to stop  in B when debug reaches this line. But please, stop on B only if A was passed previously

Comment: @vico,  it doesn't support it, we can set a conditional in B with some Parameters of A, but the debugger needs to really execute to the line B. Since the two breakpoints（in code line A and B） have the execution sequence, if A run firstly, it will hit A breakpoint firstly, it will not hit the B breakpoint unless you want to  avoid the first breakpoint with the DebuggerNonUserCode attribute here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/#

Comment: @vico, any updates? Is it the workaround you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I do c#, and I know JetBrains Rider has exactly the feature you want. Called Dependent breakpoints. So I guess their c++ IDE CLion also has the feature.

In Visual Studio, you can manually do this. Set up the two breakpoints, disable B first. Run the code, after A got hit and the execution suspends, then enable B, press continue.